# ASP.NET MVC Conditional ViewModel Abstraction

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, view, abstraction

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I am stuck on a point. I am working on a classified site. My situation is, I have a lot of categories in which a user can post their ads and each ad category have different View. I have created a Controller Action like

```
 public ActionResult PostAd(string CategoryName, string SubCategoryName)
 {
        if(categoryName == "Vehicle" && SubCategoryName == "Cars")
        {
             var model = new CarAdViewModel();

             // set CarAdViewModel properties...

             return View("CarAdCreateView", model);
        }
        else if(categoryName == "Vehicle" && SubCategoryName == "Bikes")
        {
            var model = new BikeAdViewModel();

             // set BikeAdViewModel properties...

             return View("BikeAdViewModel", model);
        }
        else if(categoryName == "Property" && SubCategoryName == "RentHouse")
        {
             var model = new RentHouseAdViewModel();

             // set RentHouseAdViewModel properties...

             return View("RentHouseAdViewModel", model);                 
        }
        else................... so on and so on
 }
```

My problem is I have huge number of Categories and Sub Categories almost 60+. And if I keep on coding like above for 60+ categories and subcategories, my `PostAd` method is going to blast and become unmanageable.

Please tell me some best practice or pattern which can bring me out of this problem.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you need a different view for each category?  Why do you think so?

Comment: @MystereMan All my ads fields are different like CarAd has : BodyType, Make, Model, MechanicalCondition, etc and RentHouse has : NumberOfRooms, NumberofBathroom, IsFurnished, HasAttachedBath etc and so on. Tell me if there is any other way?

Comment: Views and action methods need to change based on their logic, not necessarily based on the data or fields.  You can render different fields in a view based on collection types.. You should look into EditorTemplates http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/

Comment: @MystereMan It's beautiful but how will it solve my problem? I have lots of ViewModels on base of Category and SubCategory.

Comment: @MystereMan I don't think it's going to make my life less miserable as now I have to create different EditorTemplates instead of different Views. I think it's same amount of code. Also partial views can work like that as well.

Comment: Partial Views are different from EditorTemplates.  EditorTemplates are designed specifically to render types and collections of types.  Partial views are more simplistic.  EditorTemplates solve your problem because you can have a type that derives from Category, and have it render it automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, some of what you are doing cannot be avoided.  There needs to be some form of model and view selection based on category.

Use a factory pattern. Create a base class:

```
public abstract class BaseCategory
{
  public abstract string GetViewName();
  public abstract Object CreateModelFromFormData();
}
```

For each category, create a sub-class derived from `BaseCategory` and implement the abstract functions.

In your action, do the following:

```
public ActionResult PostAd(string categoryName, string subCategoryName)
{
  BaseFactory factory;
  if (categoryName == "Vehicle")
  {
    if (subCategoryName == "Cars")
    {
      factory = new CarsFactory();
    }
    else ...
  }
  else ...

  return View(factory.GetViewName(), factory.CreateModelFromFormData());
}
```

I have a couple reasons for this schema:

1. I am purposefully using `if/else` for the factory selection.  Your controller is going to be created and re-created for every action call.  So pre-populating a list will constantly and needlessly create objects for categories that will not be selected.  A simple `if/else` will be more efficient.  If you want to prevent the `if/else`, you can put your factories in a `Dictionary` and select based on the categories, but that would be a lot of needless constructor actions.
2. I made the `CreateModelFromFormData` a function because I assume you'll need to copy data from the posted form data.  This may require passing in data, but I left the function parameterless.
3. I used base/derived classes because the copying of the form data will probably need to be custom from the model being created and the form data being posted.  Also, saving to persistent storage (file or database) may be category-specific as well.

Answer (score 1):

It would be one of some possible solutions

```
public class PostAdData
{
    public string CategoryName;
    public string SubCategoryName;
    public string ViewName;
    public Type Model;
}

public class PostController : Controller
{
    private readonly List<PostAdData> _theData;

    public HomeController()
    {
        _theData = InitializeData();
    }


    public ActionResult PostAd(string categoryName, string subCategoryName)
    {
        var data = _theData.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryName == categoryName && c.SubCategoryName == subCategoryName);
        if (data != null)
        {
            var model = Activator.CreateInstance(data.Model);
            return View(data.ViewName, model);
        }
        return View("Error");
    }

    [NonAction]
    public List<PostAdData> InitializeData()
    {
        var result = new List<PostAdData>
                         {
                             new PostAdData
                                 {
                                     CategoryName = "Vehicle",
                                     SubCategoryName = "Cars",
                                     ViewName = "CarAdCreateView",
                                     Model = typeof (CarAdViewModel)
                                 }
                         };
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make your `_theData` static and populated in a static constructor. Otherwise it will be populated and re-populated for every action call.

Answer (score 1):

You should make this data driven.  You create a lookup table that has a compound primary key of category and subcategory.  Then it has a table with View in it.  Then you simply ad rows for each category/subcategory/view combination.

If you absolutely don't want a database, then you can use a simple hashset or dictionary.

```
var views = new Dictionary<Tuple<string,string>,string>();

views.Add(new Tuple<string,string>("Vehicle", "Cars"), "CarAdCreateView");
```

Then in your PostAd you just lookup the correct view.

Comment: I will prefer database approach but I am lost what to do.

Answer (score 1):

What a beautiful solution on www.asp.net to my question, here is the link : http://forums.asp.net/t/1923868.aspx/1?ASP+NET+MVC+Conditional+ViewModel+Abstraction

Edit:

My code is :

```
public class AdsController : Controller
{
     private readonly IAdService _adService;
     public AdsController(IAdService adService)
     {
         _adService = adService;
     }

     public ActionResult PostAd(string Category, string SubCategory)
    {
        //Here I will call
        var strategy = GetStrategy(CategoryName, SubCategoryName);
        strategy.FillModel(_adService );
        return View(strategy.ViewName, strategy.Model);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it will create objects on every action call looking for the appropriate class. Infact, I suspect performance will be even worse than @abbas-amiri's approach because of the extra "search for classes" that it will do. Yes it's beautiful, but you'll take a performance hit for it. If you are going to stay with this solution, then at least "discover" the classes once and cache them.

Comment: I understand that I will lose some performance with GetStrategy() method but why it will create these objects on every action call?

Comment: As part of `GetStrategy`, hidden in the LINQ statement is `Activator.CreateInstance` which will create an instance of the objects it finds, then compare your desired categories against the categories held inside that object.  Those objects are created, compared then destroy (if it's not the correct one).  You call `GetStrategy` for every `PostAd` call, so it will create, compare and destroy many objects for every `PostAd`.